# Installing short 18"- 24" threaded black pipe for lp gas line in wall

Tags: walls, pipe, gas

Is it ok to run short 18"-24" threaded pieces of black gas pipe in the wall horizontally done by a licensed plumber so it goes through the 2x6 studs

Comment: Ask the licensed plumber, or ask your Local Authority Having Jurisdiction (the town housing inspector's office, usually). They'll know what the local codes and conventions permit and forbid, in detail.

Answer (score 1):

Short threaded connections are generally acceptable, **if** your piping system passes required pressure testing. As @keshlam states, check with your local permitting authority.